# Does download window 11 from bootable usb will lost my activation key?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11

My computer has used the product key for windows 10, I now want to update it to windows 11 by using my bootable USB. If I update to windows 11 doing that will my data and my activation key will be lost?

Comment: AFAIK, updating win10 to 11 directly will preserve the key. Installing Win11 fresh will not [This also happened from 7 to 10]. Run the Media Creator from the live OS & 'upgrade this computer' rather than starting from a USB key.

Comment: Windows 8+ will automatically detects the license key and will activate. Windows 10 can be upgraded from within Windows to Windows 11. Skip the bootable USB and just use the [Windows 11 Installation Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=nOD/rLJHOac&ranSiteID=nOD_rLJHOac-yEc1wPu4x1.vd6c.9zaiTg&epi=nOD_rLJHOac-yEc1wPu4x1.vd6c.9zaiTg&irgwc=1&irclickid=_cfch6th2q0kf6zfwjvzgsp2lp22xrcjp2hvm11gj00)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same USB key for Windows 11, existing data on the key will be lost.

Best thing is to use a different USB Key if you wish to use a USB Key.

Also know that your Windows 10 license is stored in the Microsoft Licensing Server and does not depend on a USB Key.

You can just upgrade directly (no USB key needed) and licensing will be preserved (Microsoft Licensing Server).

Comment: I guess that is a yes then

Comment: The data on the key will be lost. But as I noted, not your activation. That will remain intact in the Microsoft Licensing Server.